# Thymeleaf/JavaScript - How To Set Thymeleaf Attribute using JS

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this input field:

```
<span class="formtext">SERVICE TYPE:</span>
    <input th:field="*{service.serviceType}" class="order" type="text" name="service"/>
```

It works everytime I save a value to the database. But I have a feature of adding more input fields when button is pressed.

I have this JavaScript function.

```
function addMoreService()
{
var x = document.getElementById('buttonservice');
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","text");
input.setAttribute("name","service");
input.setAttribute("th:field","*{service.serviceType}"); 
input.setAttribute("id","field2");
input.setAttribute("class","partner");
x.appendChild( input );                  

}
```

As you can see I put input.setAttribute("th:field","*{service.serviceType}"); to be able to save it just like the already seen input field. But it seems that it didn't work. The thymeleaf attribute was not set to the created input field.

It displays the error:

```
 Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that Tymeleaf is a template server-side library I consider that you can't add component through client-side code.

You could consider of have on the server side a list of object service.serviceType and create one input field for any item in the list.
In this way when you will submit the form in the new reload page you get a new item in the list and you will see a new input field in the form.

Unfortunately being a server side library you have talk with the server and reload the page on a new button pressed in order to create a new binding with the your model, that will have a new item in the list and the form.

If you need of a not reload of page you should consider of build a rest-api and use a client side framework as Angular or Backbone for sending the data.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could do it the easy way.